Strange shadow behaviour
This is what I'm trying to achieve vs. what I have so far:
 
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .border(
            width = 1.dp,
            brush = Brush.linearGradient(colors = listOf(Color(0xFFEB00FF), Color(0xFF000AFF))),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(2)
        )

        .height(353.dp)
        .width(534.dp)

        .background(
            color = Color.White,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(2)
        )

        .shadow(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(2),
            elevation = 12.dp,
            ambientColor = Color(0xFF9FA3F8),
            spotColor = Color(0xFF9FA3F8)
        ),
)


The "strange behavior" results in the shadow being applied after the background. Switch them and it should look normal again (shadow adds a graphics layer, so it overwrites the background).

@leviathan you were right bro thank you. This is my first time with compose so I'm kind of a newbie. This worked thank you.

@Leviathan That would make a good answer!  (And counter the not-so-good one.)

Building on my comment to the question, the "strange behavior" that the shadow seems to bleed inwards is caused by the graphics layer created by shadow overlaying the background. That can be easily fixed by just switching the order in which those two modifiers are applied.
I interpreted your response that this is sufficient for you, although the resulting shadow won't radiate uniformily in all directions as it does in your reference screenshot.

for the all round radiation i extended the Modifier.shadow functionality as demonstrated here [https://medium.com/@hanihashemi/implementing-custom-shadows-with-jetpack-compose-for-neumorphism-design-cd666887a642] with a little modifications

The link is: https://medium.com/@hanihashemi/implementing-custom-shadows-with-jetpack-compose-for-neumorphism-design-cd666887a642

Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(353.dp)
            .width(534.dp)
            .background(
                color = Color.White,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp)
            )
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(Color(0xFFEB00FF), Color(0xFF000AFF))
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp)
            )
            .shadow(
                elevation = 12.dp,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp),
                clip = false // Set clip to false to ensure the shadow is visible outside the box
            )
    ) {
       
    }


This is entirely wrong. Please actually test your code before you post. Then you would have noticed that the only thing that changed is the color of the shadow (because you removed it for whatever reason). Setting clip to true enforces the shadow's shape (the 2.dp rounded corner), nothing more, it therefore has no influence on the problem at hand. Your answer doesn't address the "strange behavior" (see my comment on the question for that) and it certainly doesn't make the shadow radiate in all directions equally, as seen in the first screenshot.
